# Can `max_locks_per_transaction` be increased to a very large amount?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I've got a rake task that is doing some transformations on my Rails 4.2 app's entire data set. Naturally, I want to wrap each step in a `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` so that the whole step gets rolled back if there is an error.

But the amount of SQL statements that get executed inside that `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` is **huge**, and I'm getting errors from postgres:

```
PG::OutOfMemory: ERROR:  out of shared memory
HINT:  You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.
```

Is it possible to increase `max_locks_per_transaction` to an arbitrarily huge number? Presumably, there must be some upper limit for this that I don't want to approach.

Or is there a better way to perform a huge number of actions that all get undone if one throws an exception?

Comment: _If_ you've already tried tuning your max_locks_per_transaction, it sounds like your data might be too large to perform these changes in a __single__ transaction. I would strongly advise against increasing max_locks_per_transaction to an arbitrarily high number, or you open up the door to memory instability. You may have more luck finding advice on the DBA stack exchange.

Comment: Possibly related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77928/postgresql-complaining-about-shared-memory-but-shared-memory-seems-to-be-ok

Answer (score 2):

At some point, the server will refuse to start because the kernel won't hand over as much shared memory as PostgreSQL demands.  You can increase max_locks_per_transaction to that point, minus 1.  Or you can change the kernel's shared memory settings so that you can increase max_locks_per_transaction further than that.  Of course that too will have some limit, but what it is depends on details of your OS and/or hardware that we don't know about.

But why do you need to do that?  Are you opening an unbounded number of substranactions and never closing them?

> Naturally, I want to wrap each step in a ActiveRecord::Base.transaction so that the whole step gets rolled back if there is an error.
>
> Or is there a better way to perform a huge number of actions that all get undone if one throws an exception?

Which one do you want, each individual step to roll back, or the whole multi-step thing to roll back?  If you want the whole thing to rollback, then you want it all in one transaction.

Comment: I'm migrating about 100,000 records, each with about a dozen related records, to a brand new set of tables. Right now, on my local machine, I can only do about 200 before I get memory errors. So I'm looking for a solution that is about 50 times more memory efficient than what I'm doing now. I'm starting to come to the conclusion that transactions aren't going to be a solution for me, simply because of the scale of my problem.

Comment: Individual rows are not locked in shared memory.  You could update/insert 100,000,000 rows, and it wouldn't need any more shared memory locks than updating 10, as long as they touched the same set of tables.  It is primarily tables and indexes which occupy the lock table, and it doesn't matter how many rows are in them.  Something else is going on.